# 「連続投票/反対投票の取り消し」が英語のままになっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

特定のユーザーから連続でマイナス投票を受けて
スタックオーバフローがその不正を検知して反対投票を打ち消してくれました

ですが [アクティビティ] >> [信用度] の通知欄に

`Voting corrected`

という英語が残っています

[image: 英語が残っている]

改善を希望します。

Answer (score 3):

とりあえず「連続投票が取り消されました」と訳してみました。

もし他に案があればコメントなどで教えていただけると助かります。